# RxJava 2: BehaviorSubject and Observable.combineLatest issues

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm having some issues with combining both a `BehaviorSubject` and `Observable.combineLatest`. I was able to reproduce it in a (smaller) test. Here is a test which is currently failing:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.observers.TestObserver;
import io.reactivex.subjects.BehaviorSubject;
import io.reactivex.subjects.Subject;

import static java.util.Collections.singletonList;

public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Subject<Integer> intSource = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(1);

        Subject<List<Observable<Integer>>> mainSubject = 
            BehaviorSubject.createDefault(singletonList(intSource));

        TestObserver<List<Integer>> testObserver = 
            mainSubject.flatMap(observables ->
                Observable.combineLatest(observables, this::castObjectsToInts)
            )
            .test();

        List<Observable<Integer>> newValue = new ArrayList<>();
        newValue.add(intSource); // same value as before
        newValue.add(Observable.just(2)); // add another value to this list.

        mainSubject.onNext(newValue);

        // intSource was already '1', but this is just to 'update' it.
        intSource.onNext(1); // COMMENT OUT THIS LINE

        testObserver.assertValueAt(0, singletonList(1));
        testObserver.assertValueAt(1, Arrays.asList(1, 2));
        testObserver.assertValueAt(2, Arrays.asList(1, 2)); // COMMENT OUT THIS LINE
        testObserver.assertValueCount(3); // REPLACE 3 WITH 2
    }

    private List<Integer> castObjectsToInts(Object[] objects) {
        List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>(objects.length);
        for (Object object : objects) {
            ints.add((Integer) object);
        }
        return ints;
    }
}
```

(If you comment out both lines with "COMMENT OUT THIS LINE", and replace the last `3` with a `2`, the test succeeds.)

Why is this test failing? I don't see anything wrong with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because you forgot that the `mainSubject.flatMap` still has the first `intSource` active, thus the `intSource.onNext(1)` will first trigger that `combineLatest` sequence. The `testObserver.assertValueAt(2)` then will be that single value in a `List`. `assertValueAt(3)` will contain the `1, 2` instead and the whole sequence has 4 items.

Comment: Why has the `mainSubject.flatMap` still that first `intSource` active since I 'replaced' the `intSource` with `newValue`? The test reflects what I would like to see, so I need the code changed to reflect the outcome of the test.

Comment: `flatMap` merges sources until all of them complete. `switchMap` is to 'replace' old flows.

Comment: Thank you very much! This resolved it. Your suggestions have been very helpful.